# Chaincode Instantiation fails on 3rd peer in BYFN example

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm testing `Hyperledger Fabric network`, which is based on the `BYFN` example `(2 Organizations, 2 Peers for each organization, Single orderer, 1 channel, 1 chaincode)`.

In the default example, they only instantiate `chaincode` on each `anchor peer`. What I tried to do is instantiate `chaincode` on a peer in addition to two `anchor peers`. So, the `chaincode` is instantiated on the anchor peer for Org1, the anchor peer for Org2, and the normal peer for Org1. But, everytime I tried, instantiating `chaincode` for the 3rd peer (no matter what the peer is), it fails.

For example,

```
 * Anchor peer for Org1 (success) -> Normal peer for Org1 (success) -> Anchor peer for Org2 (failed)
 * Anchor peer for Org1 (success) -> Anchor peer for Org2 (success) -> Normal peer for Org1 (failed)
```

Failed error message is `"the chaincode is already instantiated"`, which actually not.

Is there any restriction of the number of chaincode distribution? My endorsement policy is `"OR(Org1.member, Org2.member)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only instantiate chaincode once per channel not per peer.  As long as peers in the channel have the chaincode installed, they will receive the instantiate transaction from the ordering service.  The first time the chaincode is invoked on any peers in the channel (which have the chaincode installed), the chaincode will be launched

Comment: Finally, now I understand this comment after I analyzed fabric SDK and balance-transfer sample. Thanks!